# Get assets android error with netbeans, fix?

Tags: java, android, build, assets

I was looking at a fix on the following website. This websites tells you how to **fix the no assets problem in netbeans.**

http://blog.yetisoftware.com/2009/04/02/android-netbeans-and-the-assets-directory/

Problem is that **I don't have a file called "build-impl.xml"** within the directory.

In fact for my android project **I don't have a 'nbproject folder.**

Hopefully someone can tell me what I should do to fix this problem since I can't get any of my assets.

**My problem is that I missing a folder and a file! What should I do about this?**

---

__ NEW INFORMATION __

Errors:

```
02-02 13:34:41.763: I/jdwp(282): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
02-02 13:34:42.412: D/dalvikvm(282): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 766 objects / 54840 bytes in 151ms
02-02 13:34:42.422: I/Problem(282): GOT HERE!
02-02 13:34:42.662: W/dalvikvm(282): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-02 13:34:42.662: E/AndroidRuntime(282): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
02-02 13:34:42.662: E/AndroidRuntime(282): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-02 13:34:42.662: E/AndroidRuntime(282):  at tiny.bomber.LoadingScreen.update(LoadingScreen.java:33)
02-02 13:34:42.662: E/AndroidRuntime(282):  at framework.impl.FastRenderView.run(FastRenderView.java:35)
02-02 13:34:42.662: E/AndroidRuntime(282):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
02-02 13:34:46.142: I/Process(282): Sending signal. PID: 282 SIG: 9
```

Error line:

```
assets.plane = assets.fetchImage("assets.png");
```

Assets.fetchImage code:

```
public Bitmap fetchImage(String location) {
    try {
        InputStream is = assetManager.open(location);
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        return image;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I did an update on everything and it is still not open. Here is a picture of where my folder is and what I did.

[image]

In "C:\Users\USER_NAME\Documents\NetBeansProjects\APP_NAME\project.properties" I added three lines.

1. assets.dir=assets
2. assets.available=true
3. asset.dir=assets

Then I couldn't find build-impl.xml and found that I wasn't even in the right folder. I wasn't even in 'nbproject' folder. In that directory I don't even have it while my other regular java projects do. My android ones did not. So after my update I made a new project and still didn't have that folder or the file I needed.

What should I do now?

---

__ NEWEST INFORMATION__

```
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Assets {

    AssetManager assetManager;

    public Bitmap background;
    public Bitmap plane;

    public Assets(AssetManager assets) {
        this.assetManager = assets;
    }

    public Bitmap fetchImage(String location) {
        try {
            InputStream is = assetManager.open(location);
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            return image;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("fetchImage(Location)", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Bitmap fetchImage(String location, Boolean assetManager) {
        if(assetManager) {
            return fetchImage(location);
        } else {
            try {
                InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/assets/" + location));
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                return image;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("fetchImage(Location, Boolean)", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

In this class that I just posted above I added the 'fetchImage(Location, noAssetManager);' to see if I could get the image without the asset manager. What I would like to know is this possible?

I keep trying different things to add on to the location, but nothing was working. I tried the following.

1. "assets/" + location
2. "/assets/" + location
3. "./assets/" + location

**Any ideas? Long as I can get one method or the other to work ill be fine!!! Thanks!**

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your link describes an old version of nbandroid plugin. If you use the current one (supposedly you do according to your comments) then you should be able to use assets in your project. Basically anything described in http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html is expected to work because the plugin delegates building to build scripts created and updated by SDK tools now.

It means just create the folder on the disk and put your file there and it will be built correctly. If it does not then tell us more details - http://www.nbandroid.org/p/contacts.html

-Radim

Comment: I edited this with more information, but will send nbandroid an email.

Comment: Also note that I use Netbeans 7.0.1

Comment: I can't contact nbandroid by email or any other way. Every time I try something I get an email back saying I can't send a message or I can't get on a list I need to be on. (Sorry I keep adding a lot of comments, but can't help it)

Comment: 1. Remove all the cruft from `project.properties` and it should still build correctly. 2. Call `fetchImage("plane.png", true);` I mean no prefixes because AssetManage will take care of finding the resource that was included into APK file. Look at ApiDemos project in SDK samples to see how they access the asset.

Comment: Did exactly what you said. Started a new project in Eclipse instead of NetBeans this time and wouldn't you know it. Neither worked... so I am doing great. What information can I give you in order to help you assist me? THANKS!

Comment: Just wanted to say I figured it out. Thanks again! The problem was that I didn't create the assets class under the android game so the render view had nothing to pull from. I know... amateur mistake. LOL! Enjoy the +200 because you did help out!